# Asp.net MVC decimal symbol issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, floating-point, regional-settings

I have an Asp.net MVC application with a particular view that has a model with a `float` property.

My server locale says that `,` is decimal symbol and it works fine when I edit my model and enter for instance **7,5** in the text box and post it to server. Default model binder is able to bind this value as expected to *seven and a half*.

But when I display this same value using `<%= this.Model.FloatValue %>`, decimal symbol is converted to `.` which means that `<%= %>` obviously ignores server locale settings.

So. How do I solve this problem then? Which locale should be used? Server system locale which says that decimal symbol is `,` or browser locale setting that's set to `en-gb`, which means that `.` is decimal symbol.

Anyway. I just want this to work reliably.

### Some code:

My controller actions:

```
public ActionResult Settings()
{
    Settings result = this.Service.GetActiveSettings();
    return View(result);
}

[HttpPost]
[HandleModelStateException]
public ActionResult Settings(Settings data)
{
    if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        throw new ModelStateException(); // my custom exception which isn't important here
    }
    Settings result = this.Service.SaveSettings(data);
    return Json(result);
}
```

The second one is called asynchronously using `$.ajax()`.

Relevant part of the partial view:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Settings>" %>
<div class="data">Float value: <strong><%= this.Model.FloatValue %></strong></data>
<div class="data">Integer value: <strong><%= this.Model.IntValue %></strong></data>
...
```

Any my model class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents application specific settings.
/// </summary>
public class Settings
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the integer value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>Integer value.</value>
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Settings), ErrorMessageResourceName = "QuotaRequired")]
    [Range(0, 365*24, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Settings), ErrorMessageResourceName = "QuotaRange")]
    public int IntValue { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Settings), ErrorMessageResourceName = "WorkdayRequired")]
    [Range(.5, 24.0, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Settings), ErrorMessageResourceName = "WorkdayRange")]
    public float FloatValue { get; set; }
}
```

As you may see, there's nothing unusual here. Oh and BTW: Range validation on `FloatValue` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using custom `CultureInfo` when converting to string

In the end I used `ToString()` method and provide appropriate culture info. I had to provide a bit more code, but it works as expected:

```
<%= this.Model.FloatValue.ToString(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("sl-SI") %>
```

And when I need to use this culture info multiple times on the same view I simply create a view variable and store it and then reuse it with every instance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try disabling Client Based Culture? You can find it in web.config, system.web section.

```
<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="false"  />
```

Comment: Yes I tried but it didn't work. Still returns a `.` instead of a `,`.

Comment: I don't know if it changes anything because it's very simple code basically, but here you go. Check my question above.

Comment: Are you setting both `culture` and `uiCulture` properties in the <globalization> tag?